Getting data as 'undefined' at the backend when sending data using formdata in React JS + Express JS
I have a project made using React for the frontend and Express for the backend. I want to create a feature to edit data. The data being sent includes a file, so I am using formData() from React. Before sending it, I have checked the contents of formData and they are present. However, after sending it to the backend, the result is undefined. Why is this happening?
this is my code
in Frontend, modal.jsx
const EditModal = ({type, isOpen, setIsOpen, rowId, onEditSuccess }) => {
  const [shipAgentName, setShipAgentName] = useState("");
  const [shipAgentCompany, setShipAgentCompany] = useState("");
  const [arrivalSchedule, setArrivalSchedule] = useState("");
  const [arrivalDestination, setArrivalDestination] = useState("");
  const [departureSchedule, setDepartureSchedule] = useState("");
  const [departureDestination, setDepartureDestination] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:3001/api/ship/arrival/" + rowId,
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setShipAgentName(data.shipAgentName);
          setShipAgentCompany(data.shipAgentCompany);
          if(type === "arv"){
            setArrivalSchedule(data.arrivalSchedule);
            setArrivalDestination(data.arrivalDestination);
          }else{
            setDepartureSchedule(data.departureSchedule);
            setDepartureDestination(data.departureDestination);
          }
          setFilename(data.document);
        } else {
          console.log("Failed to fetch data");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [rowId, token]);

 const editRow = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formDataa = new FormData();
    formDataa.append("document", file);
    formDataa.append("ship_agent_name", shipAgentName);
    formDataa.append("ship_agent_company", shipAgentCompany);
    if(type === "arv"){
      formDataa.append("arrival_schedule", arrivalSchedule);
      formDataa.append("arrival_destination", arrivalDestination);    
    }else{
      formDataa.append("departure_schedule", departureSchedule);
      formDataa.append("departure_destination", departureDestination);
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3001/api/ship/arrival/" + rowId,
        {
          method: "PUT",
          body: formDataa,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Data successfully updated");
        onEditSuccess();
      } else {
        console.log("Failed to update data");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    } finally {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

 return (
    <div
      id="popup-modal"
      tabIndex="-1"
      className={
        "overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden z-50 justify-center items-center flex fixed bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.2)] transition transform h-screen w-full"
      }
      onClick={(e) => handleClickOutside(e)}
    >
        // ...
         <form
              className="flex justify-center items-center"
              onSubmit={(e) => {editRow(e, rowId)}}
              encType="multipart/form-data">
              <div className="grid gap-[20px]">
                <div>
                  <div className="pl-[17px] font-bold">Agent Name</div>
                  <div className="pt-[11px]">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={ship_agent_name}
                      onChange={(e) => setShipAgentName(e.target.value)}
                      placeholder="Agents Name"
                      className="pl-[17px] bg-[#83B3CA] placeholder-[#5C5C68] w-[594px] h-[45px] rounded-[10px]" />
        // ...
         </form>
};

and in backend. index.js
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true, 
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
};

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", 'public')));
//....
app.put("/api/ship/:type/:id", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const type = req.params.type;
  
    console.log(req.body.ship_agent_name);

    if(req.body.ship_agent_name === undefined){
        console.log("no data");
        return res.status(500).send({ message: "Error updating data" });
    }
  
    let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM departures WHERE id = ?";
    if (type === "arrival") {    
      sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM arrivals WHERE id = ?";
    }
  
    db.query(sqlQuery, [id], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({ message: "Error fetching data" });
      }
      let arrivalSchedule, arrivalDestination, departureSchedule, departureDestination;
      if (result.length > 0) {
        const shipAgentName = req.body.ship_agent_name || result[0].ship_agent_name;
        const shipAgentCompany = req.body.ship_agent_company || result[0].ship_agent_company;
        const document = req.file ? req.file.filename : result[0].document;
  
        if (type === "arrival") {
          arrivalSchedule = req.body.arrival_schedule || result[0].arrival_schedule;
          arrivalDestination = req.body.arrival_destination || result[0].arrival_destination;
        } else {
          departureSchedule = req.body.departure_schedule || result[0].departure_schedule;
          departureDestination = req.body.departure_destination || result[0].departure_destination;
        }
  
        const updateQuery = `
          UPDATE ${type === "arrival" ? "arrivals" : "departures"}
          SET ship_agent_name = ?, ship_agent_company = ?, ${type === "arrival" ? "arrival_schedule" : "departure_schedule"} = ?, ${type === "arrival" ? "arrival_destination" : "departure_destination"} = ?, document = ?
          WHERE id = ?`;
  
        const updateData = [shipAgentName, shipAgentCompany, arrivalSchedule || departureSchedule, arrivalDestination || departureDestination, document, id];
  
        db.query(updateQuery, updateData, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send({ message: "Error updating data" });
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "Data successfully updated" });
            }
        });
      }
    });
});
//...

why console.log(req.body.ship_agent_name) showing undefined

Hi, None of the above middleware is capable of handing multipart/form-data. You may need to add  Multer or similar middleware for it. Multer https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

I'm Really Sorry, i just need to add  upload.single() middleware in my endpoint. thanks @WeDoTheBest4You

yes indeed since there is only one file and the rest is text inputs only. Thank you for your feedback. All the best.
